# I forgot to pay for bus travel it's 5rs I don't exactly remember the bus name and how to find it what should I do?

Tags: debt

I forgot to pay for bus travel it's 5rs I don't exactly remember the bus name and how to find it what should I do? Am i in debt will I be accountable for that

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking ou [help]. What or who is 5rs? What hinders you to go to the bus company and pay your debt?

Answer (score 1):

Give 5rs as charity on behalf of the person to who you owe the debt.